# How to use multiple (multipleSelect) jquery pluggin and display the result in different inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, multiple-select-query

I'm working on a website, and I'm actually using the multipleSelect jQuery plugin, but I have a problem.

To begin, here is my problem :
I've 2 list made in HTML with `<select>` and `<option>`, no problem about it.

You've :
First list with an input to display my choices :
- a
- b
- c
- d

Second list with an input to display my choices :
- e
- f
- g
- h

It's an example of course. You're a free to check what you want in these lists.
With the multipleSelect plugin, when you check a checkbox, it display your choice in the input made for it.

Example:
If you check 'a, b' in the first list, it will display 'a, b' in the first list input.

But what I want, is when your choices are 'e, f, g' for example, it will display in THE FIRST input and not the second, 'e, f, g'.

My choices of the second list, must be displayed in the first one.

How can I do that?